# Randomized Solution to a System of Inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, inequality, vector-spaces

Given a set of $\mathbf v_i \in \{0,1\}^k$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and a vector $\mathbf x \in [0,1]^k$, we want to decide if the following inequality holds or not:

$$
\mathbf x \le \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \mathbf v_i 
    \text{ for some $\alpha_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i=1$} \tag{I}
$$
where the comparison is taken componentwise. Assume, we randomly take $m$ out of $n$ vectors $\mathbf v_i$ and call them $\mathbf u_j$ for $j=1,\dots,m$ and solve the following inequality instead:

$$
\mathbf x \le \sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j \mathbf u_j 
    \text{ for some $\beta_j$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j=1$}\tag{II}
$$

Obviousely, if the answer to (II) is *yes*, the answer to (I) is *yes* as well (because it doesn't harm if we set some of $\alpha_i$ to zero).
It is also obvious that if the answer to (I) is *no*, the answer of (II) is *no* as well.

Now, my question is that what is the probability that the answer to (II) is *no* but the answer to (I) is *yes*?

We can assume $\mathbf v_i$ are distinct. Additionally, let $\mathbf v_i = \langle v_i^1,\dots,v_i^k \rangle$. For each $\mathbf v_i$, $v_i^j$ is 1 with probability $p_j$ and zero with probability $1-p_j$. Also, assume $\mathbf x$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]^k$, *i.e.,* each entry of $\mathbf x$ is picked uniformly from $[0,1]$.

Comment: It sounds like you also need some sort of constraints on $\mathbb{x}$.

Comment: @Sam: You mean something other that $\mathbf x \in [0,1]^k$?

Comment: If you talk about probabilities, you'll have to say something about what probability measure you use to pick $\mathbb{x}$.

Comment: You are right. I just edited the question and added the distribution of $\mathbf x$. Please let me know if it is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: Any comment, answer, hint, tip, ...? None? :)